# Как изымать из таблицы по 10 элементов

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица news мне нужно изымать поочередно вначале первые 10 элементов, потом еще 10 следующих и так далее. У меня у каждой новости есть поле news_id, но оно в связи с возможным удалением новостей может прерываться к примеру 1,2,3,5,8 и так далее, тоесть точно 10 не получится получить указав BETWEEN. Так подскажите пожалуйста можно ли каким-нибудь способом получать ровно по 10 новостей из этой таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать новое поле с помощью **row_number** (название может отличаться в зависимости от диалекта sql). Это позволит сформировать нумерацию без прерываний и по ней можно уже отсеивать записи через **between**.

Comment: а есть способы без создания доп полей?

Comment: значение row_number можно использовать без сохранения его в отдельное поле. Просто используйте его в запросе.

Comment: спасибо большое